# How to combine thousands of columns into a single cell with comma separated values

Tags: excel

I have a few thousand columns in an excel doc and I'd like to combine them into a single cell and make them comma separated (without a space in between) so i can put the data in a SQL query.

Here is what it looks like today

```
A1 | 705565 739815  654970  769828  693798  277205  353553 ...
```

Here is what I'd like it to look like

```
A1| 705565,739815,654970,769828,693798,277205,353553...
```

In the past i've used a simple concatenate formula (A1&","&B1&","&C1) but this data set is far too big.  Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: Are you using VBA? Excel only? Java? What DBMS are you using?

Comment: I'm only using excel

Comment: Is this the only data in the workbook? If so, you could save as a comma delimited file (CSV file).

Comment: How many **thousands**?  Don't forget the limit on the number of characters in a cell is 32,767.  It appears you have six-digit numbers, + the comma, giving you a limit of about 4,600 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the values are in row #1, then try this small macro:

```
Sub KonKate()
    Dim s As String, N As Long, i
    Dim v As String
    N = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For i = 1 To N
        v = Cells(1, i).Text
        If v <> "" Then
            s = s & v & ","
        End If
    Next i
    Range("A1").Value = Mid(s, 1, Len(s) - 1)
End Sub
```